# 'Updated' book in the same spirit as Dieudonné's Panorama des mathématiques pures

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, ho.history-overview

Today a colleague of mine asked me if I knew of any "more modern version" of J. Dieudonné's *Panorama des mathématiques pures. Le choix bourbachique*.

The very first thing that instantly came to my mind was *[The Princeton Companion to Mathematics](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8350.html)*; however, upon careful consideration, as I see it, the spirit of these two works is different (for the context and a summary of Dieudonné's work, you may refer to [this review by P. Halmos](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183544583), for example).

Being myself interested in possible answers to the question, I'll pose it here:

> Does there exist an 'updated' book in a similar spirit as Dieudonné's
>   *Panorama des mathématiques pures*?

---

I've just found out that a similar question was asked on *Mathematics Stack Exchange*, and the only answer proposed was indeed *The Princeton Companion to Mathematics*: [*An updated alternative to “A Panorama of Pure Mathematics”*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226407/an-updated-alternative-to-a-panorama-of-pure-mathematics?newreg=39edf96d9f954fe2a4debe49aba9de1b).

Comment: I just read the review by Halmos you linked at. Very nice.

Comment: @Joël, I'm glad you liked it.

Answer (score 2):

you might consider Oddifreddi's [The Mathematical Century: The 30 Greatest Problems of the Last 100 Years](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691128057)

> The twentieth century was a time of unprecedented development in
>   mathematics: more theorems were proved and results found in a hundred
>   years than in all of previous history. Here this development is told
>   through thirty highlights of pure and applied mathematics. Each tells
>   the story of an exciting problem, from its historical origins to its
>   modern solution, in lively prose free of technical details. The book
>   opens by discussing the four main philosophical foundations of
>   mathematics of the nineteenth century and ends by describing the four
>   most important open mathematical problems of the twenty-first century.

Comment: I don't quite like the idea of "freedom from technical details", but I'll have a look at the book. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Not what you asked for, but books in a similar category to Oddifreddi's: "Mathematics Unlimited — 2001" and "Beyond & Mathematics: Frontiers and Perspectives"